# Use cmake within script

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, cmake

I want to use python cmake `pip install cmake` in my script. Is it possible to do

```
import cmake
cmake('..') 
cmake('make')
```

or

```
cmake(['..'])
cmake(['make'])
```

?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to run cmake from python, you don't need the [cmake pypi package](https://pypi.org/project/cmake/), you can instead run cmake using a call to the os in your python code.

```py
import os

os.chdir("build")
os.system("cmake ..")
os.chdir("..")
```

See [the OS python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) for more information.

From my understanding, and from reading the linked documentation to [scikit build](https://scikit-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) it seems that this cmake package is really more for bringing the python setup process and the cmake process together... From my reading of your question you're clearly just trying to run cmake, so I could be wrong, but the above should be fine.

Comment: yeah I know about 'os', but I dont want cmake dependency, can I do it using cmake from pypi?

Comment: @user13758241: Not sure what do you mean by "I dont want cmake dependency", but `pip install cmake` provides `cmake` **executable**, see [documentation](https://cmake-python-distributions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

Comment: You can't run cmake without it being a dependency in some way... As @Tsyvarev said, installing cmake through pip literally installs cmake on your system. Based on that, you saying
"I want to use python cmake pip install cmake"
and 
"I dont want cmake dependency,"
contradict each other.

If anything, you can use pip to install cmake and then run it using `os` the way I described in my answer.. This can make cmake an explicit dependency of the project if you put it in your `requirements.txt` file. Is there something I'm missing about what you want to do exactly?